# Openlayers 3 coordinate conversions

Tags: coordinates, openlayers-3

Newb alert: I'm completely new to OpenLayers 3 and mapping in general. My background is in SQL Server, and back end systems design. I have no experience in HTML, JavaScript, web development etc. I'm sure this is a very simple issue but I can't seem to figure out the details.

I've modified one of the samples for OpenLayers.org and it doesn't behave as expected. It uses a GeoJSON object and draws points on the map, but they don't end up where expected. Apparently there is some conversion or something that happens.

The sample I used is here: [GeoJSON example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/geojson.html)

My test map is here: [Test Map](http://74.69.121.94/)

The GeoJSON object is defined as

```
        var geojsonObject = {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'crs': {
                'type': 'name',
                'properties': {
                    'name': 'EPSG:3857'
                }
            },
            'features': [
              {
                  'type': 'Feature',
                  'geometry': {
                      'type': 'Point',
                      'coordinates': [0, 0]
                  }
              },
              {
                  'type': 'Feature',
                  'geometry': {
                      'type': 'Point',
                      'coordinates': [-8.575653e6, 4.70681e6] 
//White House, Washington DC Lon -77.03648269999997 Lat 38.89767579999999
                  }
              }
            ]
        };
```

Through a little trial and error, I was able to get my point to display on the White House Lawn (NSA has no doubt flagged this conversation) and there is no resemblance to the latitude and longitude I pulled from a different source. I understand that the order of coordinates is [lon, lat] but I can see no rhyme or reason that -77.036 = -8.575e6. The other point [0,0] displays right where I would expect it.

I have tried to figure this out myself and searched quite a few places, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Also, if you could direct me to any good tutorials, it would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your GeoJSON data is in EPSG:3857, a different coordinate system than latitude/longitude. The coordinates are not equal, but represent the same geographical location.

See http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/ for information about EPSG:3857. The map there clearly shows the difference between a given points coordinates in the coordinate reference systems.

Answer (score 0):

Openlayers actually allows you to convert these using the `ol.proj` functions.

For instance, to convert from lat/lon (EPSG:4326) to Spherical mercator ( EPSG:3857 - the one most online web maps use, in metres) you could do:-

`var newCoordinates = ol.proj.transform(latLonCoordinate, "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");`

`newCoordinates` would then contain the converted values in a coordinates array.  Same can be done for 'extents' (the box coordinates for top left/bottom right of a map view) using `ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, fromProj, toProj)`.

Comment: I figured there was some type of conversion that needed to take place.

For this application, it seems like it will be more efficient to perform the conversion on the server, before points are stored in a database. The JSON will be extracted from the database and served to the web client. So I guess I need some transformation formulas.